# Openlayers Draw Interaction

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

[Openlayers Draw Interaction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Draw-Draw.html)

Above is the link to the Openlayers interaction that I'm using. I want to use this interaction to limit users to only draw a north aligned bounding box. Out of the box that's not how the Draw interaction functions. Is there a way to enforce the drawing to be that of a north aligned bounding box? Or is there a means of making the draw interaction behave as the Extent Interaction?

[Openlayers Extent Interaction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Extent-Extent.html)

I'm using the latest version of Openlayers and here is my draw interaction configuration:

```
const styles = [
    new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#017e01',
            width: 2.25,
        }),
        fill: new Fill({
            color: 'rgba(36, 37, 42, .25)',
        }),
    }),
];

const source = new VectorSource();
const vector = new VectorLayer({
    projection: 'ESPG4326',
    source,
    style: new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
            color: 'rgba(36, 37, 42, .25)',
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#017e01',
            width: 2,
        }),
        image: new Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new Fill({
                color: '#017e01',
            }),
        }),
    }),
});

const draw = new Draw({
    style: styles,
    source,
    condition: olEvents.shiftKeyOnly,
    type: 'Polygon',
});
```

Comment: Use the createBox geometry function in conjunction with circle type https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html

Comment: Thanks @Mike! Massive help